# Music stops when page changes Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jplayer

I have a music app and I am using JPlayer to stream the music on the page. When I go to another page music stops, I need a way out to make the steam seamless around all the pages. I am using Djnago 1.11 and Django Rest Framework.

Comment: Only one solution: don't change the page. Use [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) architecture, or frames, to stay on the same page. And everyone hates frames.

Comment: SPA is not possible